# I could not update maven on Mac Ventura 13.3.1a in spite of updating the M2_HOME and PATH variables in .zshrc and sourcing it

Tags: macos, maven-3, java-17, zshrc

I originally have maven 3.8.3 installed under {HOME}/dev/apache-maven-3.8.3 folder.

Then I downloaded the latest `apache-maven-3.9.2-bin.tar.gz`, executed

```
tar xzvf ./apache-maven-3.9.2-bin.tar.gz
```

which formed **{HOME}/dev/apache-maven-3.9.2 folder** with bin, lib etc. folder under in it.

I updated {HOME}/.zshrc with

```
export M2_HOME=${HOME}/dev/apache-maven-3.9.2
export M2=${M2_HOME}/bin
export PATH=$M2:<followed by some more items>
```

I ran $ source ~/.zshrc and queried

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.3 (ff8e977a158738155dc465c6a97ffaf31982d739)
Maven home: /Users/venkatanutalapati/dev/apache-maven-3.8.3
Java version: 17.0.7, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home

$ which mvn
/Users/venkatanutalapati/dev/apache-maven-3.8.3/bin/mvn
```

In spite of all the changes to the .zshrc, and sourcing it, why the system is not recognizing the new maven installation ?

Comment: Check echo $PATH for the old maven path, if it is there you have to remove it.

Comment: I am hoping I solved the issue, a bit unconventionally. Yuck !!
Like I renamed the existing ${HOME}/dev/apache-maven-3.8.3 as ${HOME}/dev/apache-maven-3.8.3X.
Saved the .zshrc file, sourced it, then it is returning the correct version information and $which mvn information also.
I think, it got cached some where. IDKW ???

Comment: Remove M2_HOME and M2 only add the appropriate location to your `PATH` variable nothing more... als you need to understand when your `.zshrc` is being loaded... so you have to close all your terminal instances and open a new one...

Comment: If you just `source ..` the PATH will be expanded but not replaced... based on `export PATH=$M2:..`...